# DISM RestoreHealth fail because an Invalid public key token

Tags: windows-8.1, public-key, dism

After some trouble with my OS (**Windows 8.1 Professional N**), i've decide to run the good old `SFC /scannow`, which found and repair some corrupted file.

The CBS log report:

```
2019-10-05 06:52:37, Info                  CSI    00000b2e [SR] Repairing 1 components
2019-10-05 06:52:37, Info                  CSI    00000b2f [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2019-10-05 06:52:37, Info                  CSI    00000b30 [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:92{46}]"\??\C:\ProgramData\regid.1991-06.com.microsoft"\[l:106{53}]"regid.1991-06.com.microsoft_Windows-8.1-Pro-N.swidtag" from store
2019-10-05 06:52:37, Info                  CSI    00000b33 [SR] Repair complete
2019-10-05 06:52:37, Info                  CSI    00000b34 [SR] Committing transaction
2019-10-05 06:52:37, Info                  CSI    00000b39 [SR] Verify and Repair Transaction completed. All files and registry keys listed in this transaction  have been successfully repaired
```

A second scan did not find any integrity violation of sort.

I then try to use DISM, with the following command:

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /RestoreHealth`

but i get `source files not found`.

So i download a Windows 8.1 iso, and i check the version with my installation:
[winver e WIM info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONq3C.png)

After that, i use the appropriate command to execute DISM with a local source:

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:G:\sources\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess`

But, again, i get the same error.

So i check the DISM.log file, and i found this error:

```
2019-10-05 14:20:40, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2784 TID=1744  Error in operation: source for package or file not found, ResolveSource() unsuccessful. (CBS HRESULT=0x800f081f) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
2019-10-05 14:20:40, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2784 TID=7928 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f081f)
2019-10-05 14:20:40, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2784 TID=7928 The source files could not be found; their location must be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg
2019-10-05 14:20:40, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2784 TID=7928 Failed processing package changes with session option CbsSessionOptionRepairStoreCorruption - CDISMPackageManager::RestoreHealth(hr:0x800f081f)
2019-10-05 14:20:40, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2784 TID=7928 The source files could not be found; their location must be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg
2019-10-05 14:20:40, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2784 TID=7928 Failed to restore the image health. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_CleanupImage(hr:0x800f081f)
2019-10-05 14:20:40, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2784 TID=7928 Failed while processing command cleanup-image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f081f)
2019-10-05 14:20:40, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2784 TID=7928 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
```

More in particular:

`2019-10-05 14:20:40, Error DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2784 TID=7928 The source files could not be found; their location must be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg`

Even if i've just done that!
So, because a couple line after the log report:

`Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log`

i open the CBS.log with Notepad++ (there was more than 11K line of logs in there) and i find a SYN in there.

Screenshot:

- [SYN char in package name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U57Xn.png)
- [SYN char in public key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEEyA.png)

So, my question is: **how this could happen?** and of course **How i can fix this?**

Some more info: Windows update work fine (i guess), but lately i get some error message regarding remote procedure call just after login (with Task Manager and some time even with explorer, when i try to oper a folder, but just the first time). A couple time i get the same error when i put my password at login.

Comment: Can you (from the logs) find the incompatible software and uninstall it/  Otherwise your options at this point are ( so far as I know) somewhat limited. You can do a Windows 8.1 Refresh (recovery options) and that keeps Data and Windows 8.1 apps but you would have to install your other software.  Is it feasible to upgrade to Windows 10 ?

Comment: A new installation or an upgrade to win10 is totally feasible (i still keep win8.1 just because i have tons of software and data and configuration, so much stuff wich means _days_ of work gone for me, to get a useful system again).

There is no incompatible software et simila listed on the log, so i don't think that's the problem, i even uninstall the antivirus and some other program just to rule out that.

Answer (score 0):

You should never run `SFC /ScanNow` before running `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` due to the fundamental purposes of both commands:

- DISM's `/RestoreHealth` checks the backups of all system files contained within `%WinDir%\WinSxS` against known good copies from Windows' Update servers.

  - *There are times when `/RestoreHealth` may fail due to a dirty Component Store [`WinSxS`]: 
     `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup`*
- SFC'S  `/ScanNow` checks all system files within `%WinDir%` (excl. `WinSxS`) against the known good backup copies contained with `WinSxS`.

By running SFC first, the user has no idea if the backup files in the Windows Component Store, which is what SFC relies upon for hash comparison to check for corruption, are not corrupted; 
 DISM is what ensures this.

1. Connect to internet
2. `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup`
3. **Internet Access:** 
    `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` 
    **No Internet Access or the above fails:**

   - Mount the `install.wim` 
      *Normally contains 4 images, always containing at least 2 images 

      **Note:** 
      For a long time, DISM on Win8.1 couldn't source WIMs, erroring out when attempted. 
      I'm unsure when / what KB applied the fix - to prevent confusion, I always recommend not sourcing a WIM directly, but mounting it and sourcing `WinSxS` directly.*

     ```powershell
     # Create Mount Directory:
       mkdir "C:\Mount"

     # Get image index for installed version of Windows:
       DISM /Get-WIMinfo /WIMfile:"Z:\install.wim"

     # Mount image index:
       DISM /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Install.wim" /Index:<#> /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /ReadOnly

     # Specify WinSxS source for DISM:
       DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:"C:\Mount\Windows\WinSxS"
     ```
4. `SFC /ScanNow`

Comment: SFC can be run first, if DISM is not working (not uncommon) and does not further damage anything. I have done this lots of times. DISM is always best, but it does not always work.

Comment: That's the thing, every guide i ever read on internet state the same thing: use `SFC` **first** and **then** `DISM` no matter what.

Right now i'm testing this solution, so brb.

Comment: So, just finished, and **no luck**. Basically i get the same result, and i tried both online and _offline_ (with the ISO mounted).

I'm pretty sure this corrupted public key token is the problem.

Comment: @John I didn't say it can't, I said it shouldn't.  @PRim, if guides are telling you that, they're wrong.  I explained why DISM should always be ran first, but if you'd like further clarification, please review the Microsoft Docs and it'll tell you the same thing.  Please take the time time understand what the Windows Component Store (`%WinDir%\WinSxS`) is, and how it functions in relation to SFC and DISM _(which is why I provided a basic explanation, as it's clear many hava a factually inaccurate understanding of this)_.

Comment: @PRiM You can try copying out the mounted `%WinDir%\WinSxS` directory, as that will pull the actual files out of the image _(they're essentially placeholders, as the entire image isn't mounted upon a mount)_.  Beyond that, the only thing you can do at that point is boot to WinRE and try running an offline `/restorehealth` again pointing to the extracted WinSxS directory.  If that does not fix it, a [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) of Windows will likely need to be performed _(process is the same regardless of Win version)_

Comment: @JW0914 No no, i understand that, i'm sure you are right. I just wanted to point out that everyone said the same thing, probably because they copied the procedure from each other.

For the other thing, you mean copy the `WinSxS` directory (the mounted one) in another location and retry? Or replace the one on my Windows directory (seems a little agrresive ;D)?

Comment: @PRiM No, never replace, or copy anything into, the system's `WinSxS` directory... doing so is a guaranteed way to create an unstable OS, likely requiring a Windows reinstall.  Extract the `WinSxS` directory out of the correct index for your version of Windows from the `install.wim` _(I personally prefer 7zip for extractions, as it doesn't damage an image and is more efficient than mounting them - simply open the WIM/ESD with 7zip)_.  Once extracted, use the path to the extracted `WinSxS` directory for the `/Source:` parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99501/discussion-between-jw0914-and-prim).